# Add file type restriction in windows share of FreeNAS

Tags: samba, truenas

Does anybody know how to add a File Type Restriction in a  Windows Share on FreeNAS

In other words, prevent a particular file extension like .exe or .bat is to be copied in to the share.

Answer (score 3):

In samba, you can use `veto files` to prevent reading/writing some extensions. For example, you can use:

```
Veto files = /*.exe/*.com/*.dll/
```

to restrict access to exe, com, and dll files.